# How to retrieve entity name by object type code using JavaScript in CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there anyway on client side in Dynamics CRM 2011 from JavaScript to retrieve Entity Logical Name by Object Type Code?

Example: Object Type Code = 1, Logical Name is Account

Answer (score 3):

This is unsupported, but it does what you want:

```
function getLogicalNameFromTypeCode(typeCode) {
    return Object.keys(Mscrm.EntityPropUtil.EntityTypeName2CodeMap).filter(function(key) { 
      return Mscrm.EntityPropUtil.EntityTypeName2CodeMap[key] === typeCode;
    })[0];
}
```

Usage:

```
getLogicalNameFromTypeCode(1); // 'account'
```

[Source](https://blog.hompus.nl/2015/05/28/entity-type-code-using-javascript-only/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively don't use the object type code at all. Sort of depends on what your exact usage is, but usually you can get straight to the entity name.

For example, `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName()` returns the name of the current entity.

[Xrm.Page.data.entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720%28v=crm.5%29.aspx#BKMK_getEntityName)

Answer (score 0):

There's a super easy way.

Using Chrome, and in your CRM site( basically anywhere,) hit F12 go to console, and type:

```
Mscrm.EntityPropUtil.EntityTypeName2CodeMap
```

You will see the full list(as picture below) of the EntityTypeName and their Type Code(including your customized entities!)

[The sameple list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJzO8.png)